How much can a top plate in an exterior bearing wall be notched?
I'm trying to run a 2" vent through my 2x4 exterior wall for my double lav, and I'm wondering how far an I allowed to notching it?
R602.6.1 says anything more than 50% needs a strap, but I can't find anything that specifies the maximum.

Usually top and bottom plates are more for keeping the wall straight and keeping the studs in place.  Unless you have joist ends.trusses, rafters sitting on that section.Guessing with more than 50% missing, they do not expect that piece to not stay together or not bend from wind.  The strap/s are probably good for close to 100%.

Got it, I'll try to take not much more than needed. Should be able to leave an inch, which is better than 25%.  I'll double check where the rafters are landing there too

If load bearing(joists/rafters/trusses), it might better to bring the vent inside and make a chase(box), cabinet(?) around it, than cut/notch the top plate the full size of the pipe.
